# JavaScript 2-Dimensional Array.push()

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

When pushing:

```
a=[ ['','','','','','','',''] ];
a.push("['','','','','','','','']");
```

or

```
a=[ ['','','','','','','',''] ];
a.push(new Array(8));
```

I want to get:

```
a=[ ['','','','','','','',''], ['','','','','','','',''] ];
```

as a result, but instead, I get:

```
a= [ ['','','','','','','',''], '','','','','','','','' ];
```

I ONLY want ONE element added (with 8 sub-elements inside).
Instead, I now have 9 elements.
it's messing with my array.length values, as you could imagine!

I understand that:

```
a.push('','','','','','','','');
```

will add the 8 extra elements as if I pushed each one separately.

even I tried:

```
EmptyData=['','','','','','','',''];
a.push(EmptyData);
```

and STILL got 8 elements added.
what am I doing wrong?

Short solutions or jsfiddle would be a wonderful holiday gift.

Comment: `a.push("['','','','','','','','']");` you are pushing a string, not an array

Comment: http://jsbin.com/hemalomudi/1/edit?js,console — Cannot reproduce. Top level array has two members, each of which is an array with 8 members.

Comment: `a.push(['','','','','','','','']);` works as expected.

Comment: Who is close voting and downvoting it, without even leaving a comment? There is nothing wrong with this Question.

Comment: @Ronk was you question answered?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a.push("['','','','','','','','']");` you are pushing a string `"..."`, not an array

This will work fine:

```
a=[ ['','','','','','','',''] ];
a.push(['','','','','','','','']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick to create a *normal* array of N elements:

```
var arr_of_n_elements = Array.apply(null, Array(n));
```

To create an `m x n` array, just use this trick twice:

```
var m_n_arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(function() {
   return Array.apply(null, Array(m));
});
```

With this approach, each element of this array will be `undefined` (but it'll be a proper array - iterable, etc. - otherwise). To use a specific value, just add another - filler - `map`:

```
var empty_val = '';
var m_n_arr = Array.apply(null, Array(m)).map(function() {
   return Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(function() {
     return empty_val;
   });
});
```

If your target platform supports [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill), it gets even more concise:

```
var m_n_arr = Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(function() {
   return Array(m).fill(empty_val);
});
```

Do not fall into the trap of oversimplification: this...

```
var m_n_arr = Array(n).fill(Array(m).fill(empty_val));
```

... will create an array of exactly the same objects. Now, when you change the value in one row:

```
m_n_arr[0][0] = '42';
```

... it means all the elements of 0-th column become equal to '42' too. And that's hardly what you want to see. )

Comment: I'm interested in what `Array.apply(null, Array(n))` does? I only know `Array(n)`

Comment: As I said, it creates a normal array. Try to do `Array(n).map((x) => console.log(42));` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for any length:

```js
var a = [['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']];
a.push(Array.apply(null, { length: 8 }).map(function () { return ''; }));
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

For best practice you should assign the other array as a variable.

```
var x = [ ['', '', '', '', ''] ],

y = ['', '', '', ''];

x.push(y);

console.log(x);
```

This will return `[ [ '', '', '', '', '' ], [ '', '', '', '' ] ]`

Here is a repl for it https://repl.it/BaQT/0

Comment: Why would it be "best practice" ?

Comment: That's why I usually try to do it that way. But, I DID actually FIND THE PROBLEM. It was initially initialized as: a=[ ['','','','','','','',''] ];  (initially initialized SOUNDS redundant, but in THIS CASE is more than needed for clarity!) but there was a command on ANOTHER referenced .js file that under a set of conditions would re-initialize it as:    a=['','','','','','','',''];   THAT was what was breaking out of the 2nd dimension and making the additions to the wrong part.